# How to delete user accounts in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I created multiple accounts as described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html).

Is there a way to delete some user account?

Is there a way to see all the existing user accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deletion and listing of user accounts created with Firebase Simple Login has been enabled once again in Forge, and will list the email / password-hash mappings as well as allow you to delete those mappings.

Keep in mind that Firebase only automatically stores an email address / password hash combination for Simple Login, and stores it separately from data in your Firebase so that you don't have to worry about managing that data securely.

This means that if you are storing user account data in your Firebase tree following a structure such as /users/$user, then you can always access the data via Forge (accessed at `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`) and view / modify your data there. I'll follow-up here once we've made progress to the Simple Login account management functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rob! With the current functionality, what would be the recommended method to restrict all changes only to specific users?

Comment: Hi Misha - Can you elaborate with the type of restrictions that you would like to allow? Feel free to ping me directly at rob@firebase.com if that would be an easier communication channel. Thanks! (And, thanks for the typo fix!)

Comment: While this resolves userdata, and allows for the manual deletion of user accounts, it does permit deletion of user accounts through the API. Since there is no way to reset user passwords,